# Why do I get only hear noise after changing the audio input in java?

Tags: java, audio, microphone

I initialize the `AudioInputStream` like this:

```
dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getAudioFormat()) ;
targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
targetDataLine.open(getAudioFormat());
targetDataLine.start();
```

That works fine and I can hear the Audio Input of the Microphone.

If I try to change the Audio Input to another device I only hear noise. I tried to solve this problem for a week now and I really don't have a clue anymore why I can't hear the other audio input device... I would be very proud about any help!

```
Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {
    Mixer currentMixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[cnt]);

    if (mixerInfo[cnt].getName() == combo1.getSelectedItem().toString()) {
        System.out.println("Gewählter Input gefunden");

        if (targetDataLine.isRunning()) {
            targetDataLine.stop();
        }

        targetDataLine.flush();

        if (targetDataLine.isOpen()) {
            targetDataLine.close();
        }

        dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, getAudioFormat());
        try {
            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) currentMixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            targetDataLine.open(getAudioFormat());
            targetDataLine.start();

        } catch(LineUnavailableException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

For complete code, go to [github](https://gist.github.com/flextexmex/e2fad97b7e1af93d6c98)

Comment: I think this has been asked before. I am trying to find it.

Comment: join me in this chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64575/why-do-i-get-only-hear-noise-after-changing-the-audio-input-in-java

Comment: I posted why `drain()` didn't work for you in the chat. It makes sense now. I guess I was partially right being a problem with your stream.

Answer (score 0):

I am certain the problem is in the `actionPerformed()` method:

```
dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info( TargetDataLine.class , getAudioFormat() ) ;
try {
    targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) currentMixer.getLine(dataLineInfo) ;
    targetDataLine.open(getAudioFormat());
    targetDataLine.start();
    // TODO: You must read what's in the buffer here

} catch (LineUnavailableException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

When the `Microphone2` object is first created, this part is invoked:

```
public void run(){

    while(continueLoop){

        n = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);

        updateMeter();

        try {
            Object_Output_Stream.writeObject(tempBuffer);
            Object_Output_Stream.reset();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            continueLoop = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the buffer is read and the output stream is filled with what was in the buffer.  This does not happen when the `actionPerformed()` is invoked.

Comment: I tried it your way. I created a new thread and stopped the old for every new input but it doesnt change anything.

Comment: Ok so far I now know that changing the input device isnt the problem. The problem is that I only can get the input of the primary input device.